# How to route the URL to separate views based on the value of a certain query parameter in urls.py Django?

Tags: python, django, api

I've recently started with Django and I'm unable to understand how to route the URL based on the value of a 'action' parameter which'll be passed along with some other parameters in the URL. So the goal is to filer out the value of the 'action' parameter and routing the url to seperate views accordingly.

For example..

If the URL is:-

`/api/?param1=value&param2=value&action=status`

it should be routed to the status view

if it's

`/api/?param1=value&action=add&param2=value`

be routed to the add view

and so on no matter the value and position of the other parameters.

Comment: You can't. You will need to encode the decision in the view itself. The *querystring* is *not* part of the path, so the URL routing does not even take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm unable to understand how to route the URL based on the value of a 'action' parameter which'll be passed along with some other parameters in the URL.

The part after the question mark (`?`) is called the [*querystring* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring). It is *not* part of the path, hence the Django routing mechanism does not take it into account. You can access these parameters with [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), which is a [**`QueryDict`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict). A `QueryDict` is a dictionary-like object, but a key can map to multiple values.

You will need to perform the correct action in the view itself. So you can implement a path like:

```
# myapp/urls.py

from django.urls import path

from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', views.myapi, name='api')
]
```

In the view you can then specify how to act accordingly:

```
# myapp/views.py

def myapi(request):
    if request.GET.get('action') == 'add':
        # …
        pass
    if request.GET.get('action') == 'status':
        # …
        pass
    # …
```

However in Django web applications, often the action is part of the path. So one makes urls that look for example like:

```
api/model1/
api/model1/pk
api/model1/add
```